# I want to finish the level with 2 players at the door. How do I do it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: Here is my game I have 2 players and I want them both to go to the door to finish the level]

here is my code for the trigger

`

```
private AudioSource finishSound;

private bool levelCompleted = false; //play the audio once
void Start()
{
    finishSound = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Player1" && !levelCompleted)
    {
        CompleteLevel();
        levelCompleted = true;
        Invoke("CompleteLevel", 1.5f); //delay finish
    }
}

private void CompleteLevel()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);

}
```

}`

I know this code is only for one Player. How do I do it requiring 2 players at the door to finish the level?

Answer (score 3):

An approach for this would be to cache the players and check against the total count. To see if it's a player, I'd advice to use [tags](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html) instead of using the name of the object for a lot of reasons. I assume, the tag "Player" is used to identify the player.

```
List<GameObject> players = new List<GameObject>();

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    // Add a new player if they enter the trigger
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && !players.Contains(collision.gameObject))
    {
        players.Add(collision.gameObject);
    }

    // Both players are in the trigger
    if (players.Count == 2 && !levelCompleted)
    {
        CompleteLevel();
        levelCompleted = true;
        Invoke("CompleteLevel", 1.5f); //delay finish
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    // Remove a player if they leave the trigger again
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") && players.Contains(collision.gameObject))
    {
        players.Remove(collision.gameObject);
    }
}
```

If you have a varying count of players, you probably don't want to hard code the amount of players in a trigger. You should have a total count somewhere to check against. A game manager of sorts, that tracks the expected amount of players.

Comment: If you don't need the references for anything else a simple `byte` counter should be enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create flags for each player, not one. When player one enters the trigger, you set `playerOneCompleted = true`. Then, you check if second player also completed. If that's the case finish the game if not, do nothing.

What you would need to add is the method `OnTriggerExit2D` to set flags of respective players to false when they exit the area.

Since the code you presented is inside the player, I would advise moving it to the door's trigger, so you can reference both players more easily.

Comment: What do you mean by adding flags? Sorry I'm not that good at programming yet. Also this code is inside the Door not the player.

Comment: Flag is simply a bool. So you need to check if both flags are true at the same time: if(playerOneCompleted && playerTwoCompleted) finish the game